# ondblclick is never fired on IE11 - Need to disable events on parent window after opening modal dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, click

I'm opening a modal popup dialog  and have this issue on IE11 - user able to do double click on parent window(I'm cancelling all events when it occurs - but with 2 fast clicks the parent window element can be clicked). I need to avoid this

```
var objCapture = objWindow.document.body;
if (!objCapture) return;
objCapture.setCapture();
objCapture.onclick = this.method;
objCapture.ondblclick = this.method;
objCapture.onmousedown = this.method;
objCapture.onmouseup = this.method;
objCapture.onfocus = this.method;
objCapture.oncontextmenu = this.method;
```

Code snippet :

```
this.method = function () {
objThis.checkFocus(); //to adjust focus on parent window
return false;
};
```

I'm facing issue only on IE11 - ondblclick is never called. User is doing 2 fast clicks and is able to perform click events on parent window which is not as expected. Can you help me find a solution for this.

Sequence of events for click on IE : mousedown, focus, mouseup
Sequence of events for double-click on IE : mousedown, focus, mouseup, mousedown, focus, mouseup, click